# Object design for WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am writing a small WCF service to return an address based on GPS data. It's just a learning app for myself.

At the moment, my WCF exposes an object type called GpsData, which has a Lat and Long. It's decorated as a `[DataContract]`.

And then I have a method, `getLocationByGpsData (GpsData);`

On a project I recently worked on, they would have done it differently. They had an object called `LocationByGpsDataRequest`, which then contained a GpsData object. And it would return a '`LocationByGpsDataReply` object, which had the GpsData object, as well as some extra address related data.

So:

```
LocationByGpsDataReply reply = getLocationByGpsData(new LocationByGpsDataRequest { Lat=...; long=...' };
```

Firstly, is their model better? Maybe it's more readable?

Secondly, I don't really want to expose the GpsData object by it's self. It's ALWAYS contained in a parent class.

```
var latitude = reply.GpsData.Latitude;
```

Is there a way to 'hide' GpsData is a stand alone object, so that when the client sees a list of `ObjectTypes` exposed by my WCF service, they only see the ones I intend them to use? Hope that makes sense...

Comment: so you only want to expose Lat and Long and not the whole GpsData-object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i agree that the their approach is better.

Also, the problem of hiding the attributes(lat, long) inside the GPSdata object can be achieved by using [Ignore Properties] tag.